# Android: Making a simple animation set

Tags: android, android-animation

I am making an interactive walkthrough for one of my apps, and in a couple of spots an alpha animation and some various other UI changes (such as checkbox pressed states) would be really great.

The walkthrough has a back and next button. The basic idea is that the next button would start the animation (maybe as a thread?), and if at any point in the animation the back button was pressed, that the animation would stop.

I have looked into the built in Android animation library, but have sort of seen a lot left to be desired. My next thought was a thread, but I know I can't change the UI from an outside thread. Also I want to leave the UI thread open for my back button listener.

Any thoughts on how these simple animations could be achieved?

Comment: why do you need a thread for an animation? looks like that's the only part that's holding you up.

Comment: Sort of, I want a bunch of ui changes to occur over a period of time

Comment: what kind of animation do you want to display?

Comment: Alpha changes, and View changes (such as buttons and checkboxes changing state etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right you can't update UI elements directly from another thread. But you can do this indirectly with Handlers. Handlers are basically a type of IPC that allows you to queue up messages to the UI for proceessing. So what you do is basically create a Handler in your Activity and pass this handler to your process thread. When there's something you want to update in the UI from the process thread just do mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(UPDATE_SOME_VIEW).

Take a look at handlers [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).